# How to insert char at specific location throughout the string?

Tags: java

I want to insert chars at specific location alternatively like :

input : orange

output : or##an##ge##

This is what I've tried:

```
String output = input.substring(x,x+2) + "00" + input.substring(x+2,x+4) + "00" + input.substring(x+4,x+6) + "00" + input.substring(x+6,7) + "00";
```

Comment: Have you tried coding it?

Comment: Bonus points to anyone who can do this in a single line with `String.replaceAll`.

Comment: @ItamarGreen Yeah I tried using substring ..also got my output..I need to have the same format for any input ....   input : programming output : pr##og##ra##mm##in##g##

Comment: @Avudai Well... always post what you've tried...

Comment: String output = input.substring(x,x+2) + "00" + input.substring(x+2,x+4) + "00" + input.substring(x+4,x+6) +  "00" + input.substring(x+6,7) + "00" ;   @ItamarGreen

Comment: @Avudai in the question body

Comment: @Tim `System.out.println("orange".replaceAll(".{2}","$0pp"));` Is there a better one?

Comment: @jay Bummer you should have posted that earlier.

Comment: Hey guys ,,,I am getting my desired output only if my string length is 7,else it throws "String index out of range"  .... Am stuck at the end of code {input.substring(x+6,7)} <<< 
String output = input.substring(x,x+2) + "00" + input.substring(x+2,x+4) + "00" + input.substring(x+4,x+6) + "00" + input.substring(x+6,7) + "00" >>>  @jay